# Working with multiple array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like this :

**$optionarray:**

```
 array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Extension" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Extension" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "10" } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "Formation" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

**$dataarray:**

```
 array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(23) "Physical room" [1]=> int(1) [2]=> string(7) "12,00 €" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(26) "user desk" [1]=> int(4) [2]=> string(7) "40,00 €" } }
```

**$fullarray:**

```
 array(5) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(23) "Physical room" [1]=> int(1) [2]=> string(7) "12,00 €" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(26) "user desk" [1]=> int(4) [2]=> string(7) "40,00 €" } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Extension" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Extension" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "10" } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "Formation " [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" } } [3]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Extension" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "Formation" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> NULL } [4]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "Formation " [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } }
```

**My fullarray** has not a unique structure , I want just to add **$optionarray** to **$dataarray** and iterate on **$fullarray**

My code :

```
$data[0] = array('Physical room', $nbprice, $totalprice);
$data[1] = array('user desk', $nbuser, $totaluserprice );

$i=2;

for($j=0;$j<count($optionsdata);$j++){
       $data[$i]=array($optionsdata[$j],$optionsdata[$j+1],$optionsdata[$j+2]);
      $i=$i+1;
 }
```

How can I proceed for create my **$fullarray properly** for iterate and display each value ?

**Expected output:**

```
 array(5){
                     [0]=>array(3){ [0]=> string(23) "Physical room" [1]=> int(1) [2]=> string(7) "12,00 €" } 
                     [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(26) "user desk" [1]=> int(4) [2]=> string(7) "40,00 €" }
                     [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Extension" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "10" } 
  [3]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Extension" [1]=>   string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "10" } 
                     [4]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "Formation " [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" }
   }
```

Comment: to add two arrays, you can use array_merge()

Comment: @Manashvibirla I tried but It doesn't work

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: @Uchiha see my edit for the output